# Centering imgs in css

Tags: css

I want to keep the center of a background img to stay the center when using different devices. how can I do this?
css

```
.front-pg {
min-height: 100vh;
background-image: url("img/IMG_20190818_145341.jpg");    
background-size: cover;   
align-items: center; }
```

html ex:

```
<div class="ex">
    <p>help me<p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hit the snippet button and paste your code into the HTML and CSS fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `align-items: center;` it has nothing to do here, use `background-position: center center;`

As a friend suggested before me to check [This page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) you can also check these pages for more-

1. [CSS Backgrounds](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp)
2. [CSS Background Shorthand Property](https://www.webfx.com/blog/web-design/background-css-shorthand/)

```html
<style>
  .bg {
    height: 300px;
    background: url(https://i.imgur.com/Q15joxK.jpeg) no-repeat center center / cover;
  }
</style>

<div class="bg"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to add the `background-position` property to the class, and add the class to a div or any tag, keep in mind that this will keep the background in the center of the div you select, if you want the image to stay always present in the back of the device, you need to create a div with the property `position: fixed`

```
.front-pg {
min-height: 100vh;
background-image: url("img/IMG_20190818_145341.jpg");    
background-size: cover;   
align-items: center;
background-position: center;
 }
```

Check [This page](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-position.asp) for reference